# Mesh movement method causing force oscillations in benchmark 2D FSI problems

Tags: mesh, fsi

I'm relatively new to the FSI world, and I'm dealing with some benchmark FSI problems at first; such as the example of a flap in a channel.  (googling fsi benchmark flap 2D leads me to the example immediately)

Currently I'm testing alternatives to mesh movement methods, i.e., not using a PDE to resolve the mesh movement, in an ALE(Arbitrary Lagrangian Eulerian) context. The solid which is in a flow channel of the fluid moves as a result of the fluid forces; namely the fluid forces give the solid body a displacement, which then affects how the fluid flows and so on.

However, whatever I try to do, even though the mesh stays valid, and the quality is more or less the same as with the PDE-based approaches, I get some weird oscillations in the fluid forces (but not in displacements, there I only have slight errors as a result). I was wondering whether such an effect is known and perhaps whether I could find more about it somewhere. Does the mesh movement somehow need to be "continuous" with respect to the displacement? I know the question might not be specific enough, but I was just hoping to find out whether this effect is something known a bit more generally. I also hope this is the right place to ask!